# DSL connection setup in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, dsl

How can I set up my DSL connection on Ubuntu 16.04? The way I set up a DSL connection in Ubuntu 14.04 is not working in Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem through following steps:

1. go to terminal
2. type `sudo pppoeconf`
3. it will ask some question, press yes
4. when you want to start internet just type  `sudo pon dsl-provider`  to connect to internet
5. type this to turn it off  `sudo poff`

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial is going to show you how to setup a PPPoE connection in Ubuntu from the terminal.

1. Open up your terminal and type the following command to set your PPPoE connection.

   ```
   nmcli con edit type pppoe con-name “YOUR_CONNECTION_NAME”
   ```
2. Enter your DSL account and password provided by your ISP and save your settings in the following commands.

   ```
   set pppoe.username YOUR_DSL_ACCOUNT_USERNAME
   set pppoe.password YOUR_DSL_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD
   save
   ```

   Then it will prompt asking:

   ```
   Saving the connection with ‘autoconnect=yes’. That might result in immediate activation of the connection.    
   Do you still want to save? (yes/no).
   ```

   Type `yes` and quit.

   [image: Setting DSL connection in terminal]
3. Finally, select DSL connection from the network settings menu to establish the connection.

   [image: Choose DSL connection to connect]
   <sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

References: https://medium.com/@dineshsonachalam/creating-a-dsl-connection-on-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-c5b7845beea0

Comment: nmcli works great, but I found that, command is little different in `Ubuntu 18.04`

Answer (score 0):

Just run `sudo pppoeconf` in terminal.
Then give your username and password in popup windows.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem yesterday, and I tried all the above options but this did not work.
However, today, after comparing the dsl-provider file on my Ubuntu 16.04 computer with the file that has the same name on my Debian 8.8 computer, I noticed that there was an error in the Ubuntu file.
So I fixed the file this way:

```
# Minimalistic default options file for DSL/PPPoE connections

noipdefault
defaultroute
replacedefaultroute
hide-password
#lcp-echo-interval 30
#lcp-echo-failure 4
noauth
persist
#mtu 1492
#persist
#maxfail 0
#holdoff 20
plugin rp-pppoe.so
nic-enp3s0f1
usepeerdns
user "XXXXXXX"
```

where XXXXXXX is my mailbox provider.